# Parameter pack extension for variable number of std::pair elements does not work as expected

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

My use-case: I want to build a constexpr map with constant content and size declared at compile time. I'm using C++ 14. This is my current basic approach on that container:

```
template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType, size_t size>
struct ConstantMap
{
    using PairType = std::pair<KeyType, ValueType>;

    using StorageType = std::array<PairType, size>;

    const StorageType storage;

    constexpr ValueType at (const KeyType& key) const
    {
        const auto it = std::find_if (storage.begin(), storage.end(), [&key] (const auto& v) { return v.first == key; });

        if (it != storage.end())
            return it.second;

        throw std::range_error ("ConstantMap: Key not found");
    }

    constexpr ValueType operator[] (const KeyType& key) const { return at (key); }
};
```

What works is initializing it like this:

```
constexpr std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 2> values =
{{
    { 1, 2 },
    { 3, 4 }
}};

constexpr ConstantMap<int, int, 2> myMap {{ values }};
```

I'd like to simplify this by a `makeConstantMap` function that takes a parameter pack of pairs and returns a map with the correct size and key/value types, like this:

```
constexpr auto myMap = makeConstantMap<int, int> ({ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 });
```

My approach on that is

```
template <typename KeyType, typename ValueType, typename... Values>
constexpr ConstantMap<KeyType, ValueType, sizeof...(Values)> makeConstantMap (std::pair<KeyType, Values>&&... pairs)
{
    return {{ std::forward<std::pair<KeyType, Values>> (pairs)... }};
}
```

Which fails with `candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with KeyType = int, ValueType = int]: deduced incomplete pack <(no value), (no value)> for template parameter 'Values'`. Live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Wfc1bq).

It seems that my assumption that a parameter pack as template argument in `std::pair` should create a parameter pack typed to `std::pair` is wrong. How do I get this working or is it even possible to make it work the way I'd like it to?

Comment: Not the problem, but `std::pair<KeyType, Values>&&` does not make a forwarding reference.  A forwarding reference is only created when the entire type needs to be deduced, i.e.: `template <typename T> void foo(T&& fr)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe passing through an old C-style array?

```
template <typename KT, typename VT, std::size_t Dim, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto mcp_helper (std::pair<KT, VT> const (& arr)[Dim],
                           std::index_sequence<Is...>)
 { return ConstantMap<KT, VT, Dim>{{ arr[Is]... }}; }

template <typename KT, typename VT, std::size_t Dim>
constexpr auto makeConstantMap (std::pair<KT, VT> const (& arr)[Dim])
 { return mcp_helper<KT, VT>(arr, std::make_index_sequence<Dim>{}); }

// ...

auto x = makeConstantMap<int, int>({{1, 2}, {3, 4}});
```

Comment: Yeah, great. This was the kind of answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

`{..}` has no type, and can only be deduced as `initilizer_list<T>` or as `T(&)[N]`.

So call has to be something like:

```
makeConstantMap(std::pair<int, int>{ 1, 2 }, std::pair<int, int>{ 3, 4 });
```

Possible work-around, with hard-coded limit would be something like:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct MapMaker
{
    constexpr ConstantMap<Key, Value, 0> operator()() const { return {}; }
    constexpr ConstantMap<Key, Value, 1> operator()(std::pair<Key, value> p1) const {
        return {{ std::array<std::pair<Key, value>, 1>{{p1}} }};
    }

    constexpr ConstantMap<Key, Value, 2> operator()(std::pair<Key, value> p1,
                                                    std::pair<Key, value> p2) const {
        return {{ std::array<std::pair<Key, value>, 1>{{p1, p2}} }};
    }

    // ...
};
```

and

```
constexpr auto myMap = MapMaker<int, int>{}({ 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 });
```